# How to tell gcc to disable padding inside struct?

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, padding, gcc6

I’m unsure on whether it’s normal or it’s a compiler bug but I have a C struct with lot of members. Among of them, there’s, :

```
struct list {
    ...  
    ...
    const unsigned char nop=0x90; // 27 bytes since the begining of the structure
    const unsigned char jump=0xeb; // 28 bytes since the begining of the structure
    const unsigned char hlt=0xf4; // 29 bytes since the begining of the structure
    unsigned __int128 i=0xeb90eb90eb90eb90f4f4 // should start at the 30th byte, but get aligned on a 16 byte boundary and starts on the 32th byte instead
    const unsigned char data=0x66; // should start at the 46th byte, but start on the 48th instead.
}; // end of struct list.
```

I had a hard time to find  out why my program wasn’t working, but I finally found **there’s a 2 bytes gap between `hlt`and `i`** which is set to 0x0. This means that the `i` is getting aligned.
This is very clear when I printf that part of the structure, because with :

```
for(int i=28;i<35;i++)
    printf("%02hhX",buf[i]);
```

I get `EBF40000EB90EB90` on the screen.

I tried things like `volatile struct list data;`in my program, but it didn’t changed the alignment problem.

So is there a `#pragma` or a `__attribute__`to tell gcc to not align `i` inside `struct list`type ?

Comment: That looks like a syntax error to me. Is this C++ or something?

Comment: It's not a bug. In C every struct member can have unspecified padding after it. Why is this a problem?

Comment: Look into `#pragma pack(1)` but make sure it's what you really need and want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554229/memory-alignment-within-gcc-structs

Comment: @pm100 : no I don’t want to require padding. I want no padding at all.

Comment: you want alignment that is different from the default, the default alignment is with a lot of empty space in it as you have seem, this is done for performance reasons. So you have to say what alignment you want

Comment: I hope you are not trying to index a struct?

Comment: Struct definitions cannot contain initializers in C

Comment: @Fredrik : what do you mean by `index` ?

Comment: @M.M : didn’t you noticed I’m using gcc extensions ?

Comment: XY problem. **why** do you want to pack the `struct`? If that's for storing or serialisation: define the frame format and use shifts for serialisation.

Comment: @Olaf : I want a buffer with most of it‘s content fixed allocated on stack.

Comment: Can you re-org the structure, putting `unsigned __int128 i` first?

Comment: @chux : the aim of the structure is to get`i`crossing a 32 bytes boundary in the final buffer.

Comment: Interesting!  What goal does crossing a 32 byte boundary with `__int128` achieve that would not be made with say with `char x[32]`?

Comment: "fixed allocated on stack" is an oxymoron. The stack is highly dynamic by definition. It is not clear why you don't use the correct and portable way and serialise the struct field-by-field with bitshifts.

Comment: Hmmm Looks like "code" being put on a stack, maybe the first call from `main()` to set up some "protection" or "hack".

Comment: @chux : because I need to perform 128 bits computations ?

Comment: Crossing a 32 byte boundary is not needed to perform 128 bits computations.  Still wondering about that [need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642765/how-to-tell-gcc-to-disable-padding-inside-struct?noredirect=1#comment68519507_40642765).

Comment: @chux : I want to bruteforce a parser which normally does not parse past 32 bytes boundaries. It’s simpler to simply do `i++` in that case.

Comment: This is by no means a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554229/memory-alignment-within-gcc-structs Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In GCC you can use `__attribute__((packed))` like this:

```
// sizeof(x) == 8
struct x
{
    char x;
    int a;
};

// sizeof(y) == 5
struct y
{
    char x;
    int a;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

See [doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html).

Also if you rely on the addresses of struct fields, take a look at the `offsetof` macro. Maybe you don't need to pack the structure at all.

Comment: @MichaelPetch : finally found the issue : atribute was the correct spell in my language. Sorry for this automatic spell checker error.

Answer (score 11):

As touched on by @Banex

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct
{
        char a;
        int b;
        long long c;
} foo;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

The `#pragma pack(push,1)` pushes the current packing mode internally, and sets packing to 1, no padding

The `#pragma pack(pop)`  restores the previous packing

Supposedly compatible with Microsoft's syntax

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html

Answer (score 4):

The fields within the `struct` are padded in an implementation defined manner.

That being said, fields are typically aligned on an offest which is a multiple of the size of the data member (or array element if the member is an array) in question.  So a 16 bit field starts on a 2 byte offset, 32 bit field starts on a 4 byte offset, and so forth.

If you reorder the fields in your `struct` to adhere to this guideline, you can typically avoid having any internal padding within the `struct` (although you may end up with some trailing padding).

By putting the fields at the proper offset, there can be performance gains over forcefully packing the `struct`.

For more details, see [this article on structure packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing).

While using the above techniques are not guaranteed, they tend to work in most cases.

Comment: I suspect from the usage in the OPs question that reordering isn't a valid option since he is using the struct to store machine instructions. In his case straight out enabling packing (to 1 byte) is the best option IMHO.

Comment: @MichaelPetch : Yep, and the aim of my struct is to get`i`crossing a 32 bytes boundary.