# C union result unexpected

Tags: c, union

This code doesn't return as i expect, identifier should be 0xABC is it possible to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdint.h"

typedef struct {
    union {
        struct {
            uint8_t address: 8;
            uint16_t identifier: 16;
        };
        uint32_t fullAddress;
    };
} isotpAddress_t;

int main() {
    isotpAddress_t myAddress;
    
    myAddress.fullAddress = 0xABCDE;
    printf("Address: 0x%02X\n", myAddress.address);       // Output: Address: 0xDE
    printf("Identifier: 0x%04X\n", myAddress.identifier);  // Output: Identifier: 0x000A but want 0x0ABC

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
> Address: 0xDE
> Identifier: 0x000A
```

Comment: Why do you think so? The way that bit fields map into actual bits of the number is unspecified.

Comment: And you've ignored the possibility of padding in your anonymous structure inside the union.

Comment: You can use shifts and mask to get the bits you want. Like `fullAddress & 0xFF` for the lower 8 bits.

Comment: @Barmar, can the struct be modified to work as as requested or is it not possible?

Comment: No, it's can't. What you're doing will work differently depending on whether you're on a big-endian or little-endian CPU.

Comment: You could use `#pragma pack` (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40642765/how-to-tell-gcc-to-disable-padding-inside-struct)). But that wouldn't solve the endianess problem. So, it is probably just a way to avoid rethinking about the X of your XY problem.

Comment: @John ... or simply skip the bitfields.  Use `printf("Identifier: 0x%04X\n", (myAddress.fullAddress >> 8) & 0xFFFF);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gcc only answer.

To prevent padding when you use different types for bitfield definitions in the struct you need to pack it.

```
        struct {
            uint8_t address: 8;
            uint16_t identifier: 16;
        } __attribute__((packed));
```

https://godbolt.org/z/roa8sfGf8

Or as @dbush suggested use the same types.

Comment: Just be aware that padding is inserted for a reason and accessing `identifier` in this struct might force the compiler to insert extra instructions just to be able to access it. So it is a space over speed micro-optimization.

Answer (score 1):

The layout of bitfields within a struct is very much implementation defined. That being said, here's what's probably happening.

```
    struct {
        uint8_t address: 8;
        uint16_t identifier: 16;
    };
```

Implementations will often use the base type of a bitfield to as the storage unit for one or more bitfields.  Two bitfields will typically be put into the same storage unit if their base types are the same and there is sufficient space.

In the case above, the first bitfield uses up the entire `uint8_t` storage unit it's contained in.  The next bitfield sits in a `uint16_t` storage unit, so there would likely be 1 byte of padding before it for proper alignment.  That's where your "missing" byte is located.

If you change the base type of the bitfields to `uint32_t`, both will most likely be in the same storage unit with no padding between them.

```
    struct {
        uint32_t address: 8;
        uint32_t identifier: 16;
    };
```

With this change, compiling with gcc 4.8.5 on CentOS 7, I'm able to get the result you want.

But again, this result is implementation defined.  It depends on the above method of placing bitfields, as well as little endian byte ordering.  There's no guarantee this will work on all implementations.